# Change the URL of the frame using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, frames

I have got 2 frames in my page `frame1` and `frame2`. Frame 2 is displaying a html page called `rightpage.html`. So when I click the `rightpage.html` on `frame2` it needs to change the URL of `frame1` URL to `toppage.html`.

```
<html>
    <frameset cols='45%,55%'>
        <frame src='leftpage.html' name='frame1' id='frame1' frameborder='0'>
        <frame src='rightpage.html' name='frame2' id='frame2' frameborder='0'>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Could you please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a JavaScript solution, you can use the following snippet:

```
parent.frame1.location = 'toppage.html'
```

You may also use the `target` attribute of an anchor. For example

```
<a href="toppage.html" target="frame1">Link text</a>
```

**PS:** Using frames is not really advisable for modern websites or web applications, I hope you have a good reason for it.

Comment: Good job answering the question AND still advising against frames in modern browsers.